Should I accept offer to lead a project that I have limited experience in but am confident I could pull off?
We have been developing a mobile app in Delphi for over a year using the FMX multi platform framework. This application plays a big role in our business model thus it is a top priority. For a while now, we've been running into specific issues like bad code design and framework specific issues like application fluidity etc.
For some more context, the developer working on the app works only in Delphi and in his defense, some of the problems we encountered are really framework specific. This was his first time developing a mobile application as well but there are also some bad practices at play.
I am also a software developer but I mainly specialize in C# working on WPF, Windows Forms and recently on .NET MAUI. I have extensive knowledge of WPF and the MVVM pattern which can easily translate into .NET MAUI.
We had some consultants, which recommended switching to a more widely used and up to date platform depending on what we know and how much time the company can allocate for this. They also recommended trying to switch to the Microsoft ecosystem since more support is available for it rather than Delphi.
The question is, should I accept the offer of working on the application even though I lack experience in the particular subject or should I let the company outsource the project entirely? I would love to do it since it would be a great opportunity to expand my arsenal in a major way and I am certain I could do it, but then again this is a business and not educational institution.

Not yet, but it is due this week as this is the next step after initially trying to stabilize the application

Yes. Do it and learn as much as you can along the way.

Let me give you a firm warning: I've been developing a MAUI application for the past year. I'm a very experienced developer. Anything beyond the absolute standard app in MAUI is an absolute pain in the ass. The transition from WPF into Maui should be fluent except most of the stuff requires severe workaround because it just doesn't work or the framework is insufficient.

I've noticed that when I did some work with tabbed pages. Changing stuff is pretty difficult but I was thinking its the same learning curve as with WPF.

If the company offers you the opportunity, take it. However, be aware that the company may, for business reasons, outsource the whole project so that it is done in time. A common business pattern is to use outside resources to get a project started and then, bring it in house for continued maintenance. The business may offer you the maintenance opportunity. (There are other antipatterns.)

If you have the gumption to give it your all then go for it.
If you don't think you have it in you to give a new platform your full attention, then don't put yourself in the lead role.
Career growth is important, plan for success - there are number of new (to you) parts to this. They will eat up your time. That is OK if you are ready for the challenge.
Maui isn't really ready for prime time. That needs to be considered. Consultants often get their money for saying common sense things and get to leave without being part of the hard work.
One last bit of painfully learned knowledge, rewriting an existing app from scratch is always much more work that building a new greenfield project. Digging out the little hidden pieces of business logic eat up a great deal of time.

We do have full documentation on what the app does and how it does it. If we decide to rewrite the whole thing from scratch we have a solid idea of what it needs to do. I agree that MAUI is not production ready, I mentioned that platform as it is (or at least should be) the successor of Xamarin.Forms. I fully intend to use Xamarin.Forms and maybe switch to MAUI later if it (ever)matures enough

@CodeJunkie It really isn't the subject matter (tech) that is a concern for taking the lead. Anyone that codes is typically comfortable learning. You're already planning ahead for the tech. That shows your mind is wrapped around it. Being the lead means being a manager. That is what likely you'll need to learn the most. Plan for that.
